# Laravel with Ajax: Dropdown dependent Checkbox

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I want to make a role permission based view where there is a dropdown and a list of check box. But when a user choose a role from dropdown corresponding permission should be checked with with that and other will be remain unchecked. For that I used the following View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Roles</label>
    <select class="form-control input-sm" name="role_id" id="role_id">
        <option selected="selected" style=" display: none;">Choose a Role</option>
        @foreach($roles as $role)
        <option value="{{$role->id}}">{{$role->role}}</option>                        
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

@foreach($permissions as $permission)
<div class="checkbox">                       
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{$permission->id}}">{{$permission->label}}</label>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Here is the ajax part

```
<script>
    $('#role_id').on('change', function (e) {
        var role_id = $('#role_id option:selected').attr('value');
        var info = $.get("{{url('permission-selected')}}", {role_id: role_id});
        info.done(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (index, subcatObj) {

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And here is the route:

```
<?php
Route::get('permission-selected', function(Request $request) {

    $role_id = $request::input(['role_id']);

    $roles = Role::with('permissions')::where('role_id', '=', $role_id)->get();

    return Response::json($roles);
});
?>
```

Problem is I couldn't set the checkbox with the dropdown..can anyone suggest one please?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add the checkbox to the dropdown select. Instead you need to create custom dropdown with list items and write onclick functions to hide and show the dropdown. I have done like this before.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like;

```
// Uncheck all
$("[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", false);
// Check current checkbox by using unique id or value selector.
$("[value*='']").prop("checked", true);
```